# Android project and Gradle: Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android Studio project that contains several modules, I want to build a single module.
Running:

```
./gradlew :installed:assembleDebug
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':installed'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not initialize class 
com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

Root project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}
ext {
 buildTools = "26.0.0"
 compileSdk = 26
 minSdk = 15
 minSdkInstant = 23
 versionCode = 1
 versionName = "1.0"
 supportLib = "25.3.1"
}
```

Installed module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 
    "com.google.android.instantapps.samples.hellofeature"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    versionCode rootProject.versionCode
    versionName rootProject.versionName
}
buildTypes {
    release {}
    debug {}
}
}

dependencies {
implementation project(":features:hello")
implementation project(":features:bye")
}
```

Android studio running normally，The problem only occur in time of command building.
What would i do?

Comment: is there reason you are using beta 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4' ?  try using 3.3? Also make sure distribution path is update distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I changed JDK version from JDK_1.9 to JDK_1.8, this problem is solved.